# Magento Order sold/invoiced but cannot ship

Tags: shipping, invoice, order-status

I can’t seem to ship any of my orders, even though they are invoiced. I manually hit the ship button in the back end, and it does nothing but take me to the shipping page, and that’s all. It doesn’t change the order status or anything to completed.

I checked with my credit card processor and everything is paid and balanced, but I would like it that Magento processes the order to a shipped/completed status...it currently says PROCESSING

Comment: Do you see a "Submit" button on your shipping page?

Comment: No, the only buttons are add a tracking, reset, and back....

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page. Below the totals

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gOHmdui.jpg

this is a capture of the shipping page.  That's all I see, and the tracking button doesn't do anything...

Comment: Looks like there is problem with your page. Is not rendering completely. If you look in the page source and the last think you see is not `</html>` it means you have a fatal error that prevents the page from rendering. Check the php logs for more details or set developer mode & error reporting on, to see the error on the screen.

Comment: I've gotten this error looking up the source.

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setId() on a non-object in <b>/home/sevensta/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Config.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />

I've also tried recompiling...still get the error.

Comment: @Xero1 is this a custom shipping carrier?